# How to call function after submit form aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, forms

I want callback alert after submit form, but doesn't worked. Submit not execute.

Only `$("#formImpressao").submit();` worked fine.

I try too use `$(document).ready(function () {` ... :( No Success

Whats wrong?

Sorry for my bad english

```
<div id="HiddenFormTarget" style="display:none;">
    <form id="formImpressao" method="post" target="frmPrint" action="/VisualizarRelatorios/ImprimirRelatorio.aspx""></form>
</div>
<iframe id="frmPrint" name="frmPrint" width="0" height="0" runat="server">
</iframe>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#formImpressao").submit(function () {
       alert('Test');
    });
    $("#formImpressao").submit();

</script>
```

Comment: You tried wrapping your code in `$(function() { // code you currently have here });` ???

Comment: Why do you want to use `$(document).ready(function () {` ? Do you want to submit the form then alert?

Comment: You need to look up AJAX, and the use of preventDefault(). This doesn't work because the page is reloading on submit.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#formImpressao").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Test');
    //Insert AJAX to submit form data
});
```

e.preventDefault() will prevent the default action of the submit event, and then run your alert, but it will NOT submit the form. For that, you will need to use AJAX. It's simple enough to understand, and there are plenty of SO topics on the use of it, so I won't reiterate. But preventDefault() will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="formImpressao" method="post" target="frmPrint" action="/VisualizarRelatorios/ImprimirRelatorio.aspx""></form>
</div>
```

Now you can use two ways to submit the form using only jQuery,**Recommended method**

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          //instead of id selector use tag selector
            $("form").submit(function () {
               alert('Test');
            });
         });
           </script>
```

Another using id selector which is already posted

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce this situation and all right:

```
[https://codepen.io/piotrazsko/pen/mqMrgo][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) There appears to be an extra quote in your **form** tag.
(2) Have you tried your approach without the **target** attribute in the **form** tag?

e.g. -

```
<form id="formImpressao" method="post" action="/VisualizarRelatorios/ImprimirRelatorio.aspx"></form>
```